# current technology for making video chat

Tags: video, web

As a hobby I want to build website which allows people to have video conversation. The question is what technologies are available to implement it?
For example, [chatroulette.com](http://chatroulette.com/) uses flash. Are there other options?

Comment: Seems to me like a question too broad.

Comment: it is broad, but there are precise answers, with description of technology how it can be implemented.

Comment: Even so, if you check [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where ... every answer is equally valid". This might be not be completely subjective but it certaintly doesn't look like it will have a single answer.

Comment: I guess in this case there is a clear answer, since (unfortunately for @capoluca) there aren't that many options.

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2012, Flash is indeed the most suitable method for implementing a video chat in web. The state-of-the-art in HTML5 still doesn't provide a working API for capturing webcam video on the client side. *[WebRTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC)* is expected to bring such API into HTML, but will take a while before it is finalized and fully supported, though the core functionality you will need (namely, the `getUserMedia` API call) is already supported in the most recent browsers.

You can check out [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) on interim supported APIs. Or just go with Flash.